# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given( "GET /%3Cint:pk%3E.pk HTTP/1.1" 500 61744)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Help needed. I can't seem to solve this problem. New to Django here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

## template

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'details' Testimony.pk %}">{{testimony.Title}}</h1>
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path('<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='details'),
]
```

## views.py

```
def details(self, pk):
    print('1')
    Testimony=get_object_or_404(Testimony, pk= pk)
    print('2')
    return render(request, 'details.html', {'Testimony': Testimony})
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't do `Testimony=get_object_or_404(Testimony, pk= pk)` - it will probably cause an `UnboundLocalError`. Use `testimony=get_object_or_404(Testimony, pk= pk)` and `return render(request, 'details.html', {'testimony': testimony})` . That way you can tell the difference between the model class `Testimony` and the instance `testimony` that you fetch from the database.

Comment: Thanks! That is super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<int:pk>` should be used with `path`, not `re_path`.

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='details'),
```